# XSLT Input file with settings - change multiple output files

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, copy

I'm using xslt to edit multiple files. I have input file that is my settings file, it looks like this:

```
<root>
  <file>
    <folderin>/var/in/</folderin>
    <in>10</in>
    <folderout>/var/out</folderout>
    <out>20</out>
    <name>First file</name>
  </file>
</root>
```

Example file:

```
<root>
  <element1 id1="10">
    ...
  </element1>
  <element2 id2="10" attribute="xyz">
    ...
  </element2>
</root>
```

And my xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
        <xsl:template name="CopyXml" match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="file">
            <xsl:variable name="inputfile" select="concat(folderin, in, '.xml')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="outputfile" select="concat(folderout, out, '.xml')"/>

            <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$outputfile}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="document($inputfile)/*"/>
            </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

In /var/in/ there are few hundred files from which i want to only edit few (in this example /var/in/10.xml with exit file /var/out/20.xml). In the new files i want to change id1 and id2 attribute value to my "out" param

I've managed to copy those specific files with adequate names with my xslt, however i'm having problem applying any template so i could change those files. I've tried using apply-templates however i cannot make it apply those templates to the $outputFile, it's either not doing anything or appending $outputFile with copy from settings file;/ Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

---

EDIT:
Output for this example file:

```
<root>
  <element1 id1="20">
    ...
  </element1>
  <element2 id2="20" attribute="xyz">
    ...
  </element2>
</root>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the result you want to create for the "Example file" you have shown. I also don't see an "out" parameter in your code, so I don't understand where the value is supposed to be taken from.

Comment: I've added the result i want. For now "out" parameter is in: select="concat(folderout, out, '.xml')". I've tried adding apply-template in which there was out param however it always applied only to my settings file, not to $inputfile

Comment: So any attribute with the value in the `in` element needs to get a new value given in the `out` element? Is there any restriction on the attribute name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your stylesheet has:

```
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$outputfile}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="document($inputfile)/*"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
```

So, you are creating an output file which **will contain a copy** of the input file.

In order to apply some modifications, you must **apply templates** to the input file, so you need to have:

```
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$outputfile}">
                <!-- further process the input file -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="document($inputfile)/*"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
```

and of course your stylesheet **will have to contain templates to handle the input file content**, copying and modifying the relevant parts.

You could try an incremental approach to your problem:

- firstly, define a stylesheet with the rules to transform **a single input file into a single output file**
- once these templates do what you need, copy them into the stylesheet applied to the settings file

---

This stylesheet should do what you need:

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <!-- template to process the settings file -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="root/file">
            <xsl:variable name="inputfile" select="concat(folderin, in, '.xml')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="outputfile" select="concat(folderout, out, '.xml')"/>

            <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$outputfile}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="document($inputfile)/*" mode="processFiles">
                    <xsl:with-param name="outputValue" select="out" tunnel="yes"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to process the input files -->
    <!-- identity transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="* | @* | text()" mode="processFiles">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @* | text()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- update parameters -->
    <xsl:template match="@id1 | @id2" mode="processFiles">
        <xsl:param name="outputValue" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$outputValue"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notable points:

- you cannot just copy an input file, you have to apply templates to it in order to change some parts of it
- while applying templates to the *external files*, a parameter called `outputValue` is passed around; using a [tunnel parameter](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#tunnel-params) spares us the trouble of explicitly passing it every time we call `xsl:apply-templates`
- I used templates with `mode="processFile"` to process the content of the external files; in this simple situation is not strictly necessary, but while working with larger stylesheet this is a little "trick" that helps avoiding priority conflicts between the templates for the *settings file* and those for the *external files*

  - an identity template just copies elements, attribute and text nodes
  - a specific template for attributes `id1` and `id2` uses the tunnel parameter to replace the existing value with the desired one

Comment: What do you mean by "<!-- further process the input file -->"? In my case I want pretty much the same file except changes to those attributes and as I've learned it probable should be by "apply-templates". I think you are right, I didn't try incremental approach, and maybe there were some fundamental faults in my transform template. I will try to do it next thing in the morning tomorrow:)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, it's just a comment to highlight the change I made, and why.

Comment: Ok, so I still have a problem. Everything works when i start it pointing to file i want to change - I use <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates...>. However i don't know how to apply template to "document($inputfile)" - i.e. using <xsl:copy-of or <xsl:value-of. I would need something like <xsl:copy select="document($inputfile)"> <apply-templates /> </xsl:copy>. Do you know how can it be done?

Comment: @Pumar I edited the answer, adding a complete stylesheet that should do what you need, together with some explanation.

Comment: Exactly what i needed, thank you for your help:) I feel like xslt is pretty powerful language however there is a lack of good tutorials which use more advanced elements like {name()}, text() or #current.